# How can I make a tile/ grid dropdown with images using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, ms-office, bootstrap-4

I want to make a menu like the Microsoft apps selection like the image shown in the link below:

Microsoft Menu example:

[image: image path]

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <!--aria-label="Left Align"-->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownmenu">

        <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="1"><img src="1.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="2"><img src="2.png"></a>
                </li>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="3"><img src="3.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="4"><img src="4.png"></a>
                </li>

            </div>

        </div>

    </ul>

</div>
```

```css
.container-fluid {
    margin-top: 1%;
}

div.col-sm-4 {
    margin-right: -14%
}

img {
    position: static;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 5%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 960%;
}
```

This is what I have tried but,
The biggest problem is that the background of the dropdown is bigger than the content(the images) and I don't know how to make the background fit the size of the images

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your code snippet is not working properly, it shows blank, can you paste it again?

Comment: its because he has give local src of the image

Comment: Why is this tagged with `bootstrap-4` if you aren't actually using Bootstrap 4?